# Samsung SmartTV application publishing

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I have build a Samsung smart TV application, i need to know what i have to do in step by step to publish that application. I refereed [this](http://seller.samsungapps.com)

and proceed in [seller.samsung](http://seller.samsungapps.com)  but i didnt get an app id for smart TV (actually i didnt found an option to proceed with smart TV in [seller.samsung](http://seller.samsungapps.com))

Comment: Do you have a seller account?

Comment: yes. i hav one., now what i hav to do?

Answer (score 1):

After You're logged in in sellers account, click `TV` link which is located in upper right corner of the screen. After that you should see `Support` element in menu bar with option `Add new application`. Click that and follow all instructions and You should get application id.